# facebook - Like a page through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'd like my application to like a facebook page on behalf of the user with an API call.
I saw [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/) part of the documentation and tried to make the following post request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/101544000571/likes?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

where 101544000571 is a page id and got the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

I thought it's a permission problem but the application (in this case it's the graph API explorer application) has all the permissions necessary.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot like a page using the Facebook Graph API. It is not supported.
You can use the the [Like button social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

The doc mentions : "For Facebook Pages or websites that do not integrate with Facebook Authentication, developers should continue to use the Like button social plugin."

Comment: So why does it say in the docs:
"You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes connection by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments and https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes"

Comment: the documentation isn't 100% accurate in that respect. it is limited to users, posts, comments and photos.

Comment: That is about liking statues and comments on statues - not Pages themselves.